# Не получается сделать загрузку файла в одну строку в поле bytea

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, ос

пытаюсь создать и загрузить файл размером в 600 мб в postgresql  в одну строку в поле bytea  следующим кодом:

```
import psycopg2
import os

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='databae', user='db_user',
                        password='mypassword', host= 'localhost')
cursor = conn.cursor()
# создаю файл  размером в 600 мб
fileSize = os.urandom(600(1024*2))
# пытаюсь поместить файл в postgresql в поле bytea
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bytea (fileSize) VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING id", (fileSize()))
```

получаю ошибку при создании файла и при загрузке его в базу данных

Comment: `os.urandom(600(1024*2))` и тут нет ошибки? Как и тут `fileSize()`?

Comment: C:/Users/Alex/PycharmProjects/pythonProject8/main.py:8: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  fileSize = os.urandom(600(1024*2)) вот код ошибки которую я получаю

Answer (score 1):

- > `fileSize = os.urandom(600(1024*2))`
  > Тут 2 ошибки:

  - `600(...)` это использование объекта `int` как вызываемый объект, типа функции, что неверно
  - Подправим, добавим умножение `600 * (1024*2)` это тоже неправильно, чтобы были МБ нужно в степень 2 возвести 1024: `600 * (1024 ** 2)`

---

- > `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bytea (fileSize) VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING id", (fileSize()))`

  - В запросе у вас в таблицу `bytes` заполняется один столбец `fileSize`, а передаете значения для 2 столбцов `(%s, %s)`
  - `fileSize()` это будет такая же проблема как с `int`, вот только в `fileSize` будут байты
  - `(fileSize()))` тут нужно использовать кортеж, просто добавление скобок не сделает кортеж, нужны элементы и запятые, например `(1)` это просто `int`, а `(1,)` это кортеж из одного `int`, и `(1,2)` это кортеж на 2 `int`, соответственно должно быть так: `(fileSize,)`

Итого:

```
import psycopg2
import os

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='databae', user='db_user',
                        password='mypassword', host= 'localhost')
cursor = conn.cursor()
# создаю файл  размером в 600 мб
fileSize = os.urandom(600 * (1024 ** 2))
# пытаюсь поместить файл в postgresql в поле bytea
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bytea (fileSize) VALUES (%s) RETURNING id", (fileSize,))
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: @AllWallker, пожалуйста :) Не забудьте проголосовать и принять ответ :)